# An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.Session has not been configured for this application or request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-7.0

System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.ISessionStore' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware'.'

[I try to use a session to my application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqsjP.png)

Comment: Consider adding some explanations. Error mesasage-only questions are to be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add  :

```
builder.Services.AddSession();
```

You can read [Session and state management in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-7.0) to know more.

Answer (score 0):

please add
builder.Services.AddSession();
in program.cs file

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. It is certainly useful to validate the results of existing answers to confirm that they solve the problem. **Stack Overflow, however, has a built-in feature for validating answers: by upvoting them**. Please use this feature instead of repeating answers as a means of validating that they work.